# Site would benefit from strikethrough text-style option in addition to bold and italic

Tags: feature-request

Strikethrough (aka line-through) text-styling would be a convenient way to identify errors, phrases that should be removed, etc.

Answer (score 10):

You can use <s>strikethrough</s> already:

1. In questions and answers, just write `<s>strikethrough</s>`.  You can also use `<del>` or `<strike>` if you prefer.
2. In chat, the alternate syntax `---strikethrough---` is used instead.
3. In comments, strikethrough is unsupported, but [unicode tricks](http://adamvarga.com/strike/) will work for some users in some browsers.  If you *really* want strikethrough in comments, this is an option.  Support will presumably improve over time.

For reasons unknown, Jeff Atwood has decided not to add an actual strikethrough button, so you'll have to use one of the methods above.  See the feature request [Add a strike-through to the editing interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9925/215040) on Meta Stack Exchange, currently marked "status-declined".

Comment: Thanks for the markup alternatives, @snailboat.